# Excel: Value in one cell in another?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for an excel formula to check to see if a value from one cell is in another.  I want to know if information from column A is found anywhere inside column B.

So since 123 Promotions is listed in A1 and also in B1, I want Excel to tell me its a match.

Is there a way?

Example:

```
Column A
ABC Co/123 Promotions
All About You, Inc
Andrew Smith

Column B
123 Promotions
All about You
Smith Inc.
```

Comment: How do you want to compare? pairs in the same row or found A1 match in ANY row of B?

Comment: pairs in the same row.  The below answer will work for my for my initial question, but now I'm wondering if there is a way to check if any part of A1 id in any part of B1.  (ex: finding 123 in both)  Can I set a minimum limit? I don't want it to return a space as a match.

Comment: In general YES. But it's a subject for new question - accept the below answer and submit a new one, but specify ALL your requirements precisely)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of 'ISNUMBER' and 'FIND'

```
ISNUMBER(FIND(B1,A1,1))
```

This will return true if the value for B1 is in A1 somewhere